# C# Losing decimal resolution when I perform a calculation

Tags: c#

I seem to be losing decimal resolution when I perform the calculation below.  It seems no matter what number I calculate I always end up with some quarter (such as x.00, x.25, x.50, 0r x.75) in the decimal.  Thanks for the help.  I know that mph.ToString("n2") will trunk it down to 2 decimals, but why into the quarters?

```cs
int totalRotations = 0;  
int lastRotations = 0;
int diffRotations = 0;
int hourRotations = 0;
double mph = 0;
double distance = 0;


private void calcMPH()
{
    UInt16 val = CounterInputReader.ReadScanUInt16();

    totalRotations = val;
    diffRotations = totalRotations - lastRotations;
    hourRotations = diffRotations * 3600;
    distance = hourRotations * 1.8333333;  //wheel constant, (feet/pulse).  Changes per diameter of wheel.

    mph = distance / 5280;

    StatusBox1.Text = StatusBox1.Text + System.Environment.NewLine + "Load Array Rotor Speed:  " + mphWind + " : " + scan.Length;

    sensorScans.Add(Settings1.Default.Ch1c, mph);

    //Why are we losing the decimal point resolution and only limited to quarters (0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75)?
    lblSpeedValue.Text = mph.ToString("n2") + " mph";

    lastRotations = totalRotations;  //Save last Rotations per Pulse for mph calculations.  

}
```

Comment: `distance / 5280` division by an integer? `5280.0`

Comment: try using use `decimal` instead of double. add the `M` suffix to a number to make it a `decimal` type. ex: `diffRotations * 3600m;`

Comment: `double` is better than `decimal` for this kind of calculation.

Comment: Your formula `((... * 3600) * 1.8333333) / 5280` = `~1.25` So whatever whole number the `diffRotations` is - you'll get quarter results.

Comment: distance is a double, so dividing it by an integer will return a double. That's not a problem.

Comment: Aleksandar Toplek, your comment answered my question as did Charles Mager, but since yours was first I will give you the credit.  

However, I am new to the forum and don't know how to mark your comment as an answer.  Anyone wanna help a newbie? ;)

Comment: You can't mark @AleksandarToplek 's comment as the answer as it is just a comment. If you want to credit them then you should ask them to post their comment as an answer and mark that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your calculation depends on an integer, the rotations.  The smallest increment is a `diffRotations` of 1.

`1 × 3600 × 1.8333333 / 5280 = 1.25`

So each mph reading will always be a multiple of 1.25, e.g. 1.25, 2.50, 3.75 etc.

Comment: Ah, so like  Aleksandar Toplek's comment above, you guys are saying it's a math problem and not a programming problem...

I never was that good at math.  lol, thanks for the catch.

Comment: Yes, it's a quirk of your maths not any issue with the code. Sorry, credit to Aleksandar.  I hadn't spotted that comment when I started my answer!

Comment: Thanks all of you for your quick comments and answers.